# k8s initialDelaySeconds for readiness and liveliness initial delays

Tags: kubernetes

As I understand the `initialDelaySeconds` is a wait in seconds for probers to start firing the readiness and liveliness probes. If I set them to 30 seconds each will the app be actually serving in 30 seconds or 60 seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liveness probes are not directly involved in the decision to send traffic to a Pod, they only determine whether a Pod needs to be restarted. As soon as the readiness probe succeeds, the app will be determined "ready" and will serve traffic on a related Service.

So for your case, both checks will start probing at the 30 seconds mark and if the initial readiness check succeeds, the app will be serving after 30 seconds, not 60.